# Creating ActiveRecord scope with multiple conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails application with a number of Products, some of which are associated with an Issue model. Some of these products have an issue_id (so an Issue `has_many` products) and some do not. The products *without* an issue ID are a new addition I'm working on.

I previously had a named scope so that I can list products using `Product.published`, which looks like this:

```
scope :published, -> {
    joins(:issue).reorder('products.created_at ASC, products.number ASC')
    .where('products.status = ?', Product.statuses[:available])
    .where('issues.status = ?', Issue.statuses[:published])
}
```

The result of this is that I can find only products that are associated with a published issue (think magazine issue).

I'm now adding products that will not be associated with a particular issue but will still have a draft/available state. The above scope does not find these products, as it looks for an issue_id that does not exist.

I thought I could modify the scope like this, adding the `OR issue_id IS NULL` part in the last line:

```
scope :published, -> {
    joins(:issue).reorder('products.created_at ASC, products.number ASC')
    .where('products.status = ?', Product.statuses[:available])
    .where('issues.status = ? OR issue_id IS NULL', Issue.statuses[:published])
}
```

But this doesn't work. I still only get 'available' products associated with a 'published' issue. The products without an issue_id are not included in the returned collection.

(There is a window in which a product will be set to *available* before its associated issue is published, so for these situations I do need to check the status of both records.)

Here's the SQL generated by the above (wrapped for readability):

```
pry(main)> Product.published.to_sql
=> "SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `issues` ON `issues`.`id` = 
`products`.`issue_id` WHERE (products.status = 1) AND (issues.status = 1 OR 
issue_id IS NULL)  ORDER BY products.created_at ASC, products.number ASC"
```

I've already created a Product class method that takes an argument as an alternate approach but doesn't work in all cases because I'm often looking up a product based on the ID without knowing in advance whether there's an Issue association or not (eg, for the product's *show* view).

Also, `Product.published` is nice and concise and the alternative is to load all published products (eg, `Product.where(:status => :published)`) and then iterate through to remove those associated with a not-yet-published issue in a second operation.

I feel like there's something I'm not quite grasping about doing more complex queries within a scope. My ideal outcome is a modified scope that can return available products, both with and without an issue, and without supplying an argument.

Is this possible, or should I resign myself to finding an alternate approach now that I'm adding these unassociated products?

Comment: Have a look at the sql generated by this query using eg `Product.published.to_sql` (edit your question and add the result there so we can all see it) :) You can often figure out why the SQL is wrong, then backport the fix you need to the ruby scope.

Comment: Good idea @TarynEast, thanks. I've added the generated SQL which I did check previously, but I haven't really wrapped my head around joins so it didn't help me see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `joins(:issue)`. That method does an `INNER JOIN` between `products` and `issues` tables and discards all the products that doesn't have an issue_id. Maybe you could use `LEFT JOIN` so you can keep all the products regardless they have an issue.

```
scope :published, -> {
    joins('LEFT JOIN issues ON issues.id = products.issue_id')
    .select('products.*')
    .reorder('products.created_at ASC, products.number ASC')
    .where('products.status = ?', Product.statuses[:available])
    .where('issues.status = ? OR products.issue_id IS NULL', Issue.statuses[:published])
}
```

Comment: This did it, thanks! I clearly need to learn more actual SQL.